# how to use inputView property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, keyboard

I have created my own keyboard and I want to open that in place of standard keyboard provided by the iPhone in the `uitextview` to enter text.In the Apple documentation I have found one property `inputView` in the UIResponder Class Reference.
It is given on this link :-[here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
But I m not getting how to use this property.please tell me how to use this property prorpely.
I have tried to use this proerty like this

```
UIView *mainView;

@property (readwrite,retain) IBOutlet UIView *mainView;

- (UIView *)inputView {

    return mainView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a property. You don't have to override its implementation. Just use it as any other regular property and affect to it your custom input view.

```
yourTextField.inputView = yourCustomInputView;
```

Comment: thanks Ali I am trying this from many days and finally u solve this :)

now how to add click event on that view do u have idea about that ?

Comment: Like in any other views. Add buttons to handle the taps, or implement the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and the other methods of UIResponder to handle touch gestures, or add some UIGestureRecognizers, implement it depending on your needs. See [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html) for details

Comment: i have already added the all the event in my customview but that events are now working

Comment: I guess ou meant "not" and not "now" ;) The view has exactly the same behavior whereas it is used as an inputView or as a standard view that you add to your screen like usual. So the event handlers/actions should be triggered the same way, no matter if your view is setup as an inpuView or a regular view in your UI.